# Problem calculating rotation matrix around arbitrary axis

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, coordinate-systems, matrix-equations

I'm trying to calculate the rotating matrix around the Z axis in a counter clockwise direction.

In-order to do that I've decided on a vector `A [1 0 0]` and I wish to rotate it around the z axis so it'll end up as `At [0 1 0]` (90 degrees rotation around the z axis)

Let's consider our matrix `R`. Now, what I've done is set `At` coefficients to the product of the matrix `R` by the vector `A` as follows:

```
At.x = A.x * R00 + A.y * R10 + A.z * R20
At.y = A.x * R01 + A.y * R11 + A.z * R21
At.z = A.x * R02 + A.y * R12 + A.z * R22
```

Now, replacing the `A` and `At` coefficients we get:

```
0 = 1 * R00 + 0 * R10 + 0 * R20
1 = 1 * R01 + 0 * R11 + 0 * R21
0 = 1 * R02 + 0 * R12 + 0 * R22
```

Next, to make these equations right I've deducted the following:

```
R00 must be 0
R01 must be 1
R02 must be 0
others R coefficients are irrelevant to me
```

Creating the matrix so far:

```
0     1     0
0     0     0
0     0     0
```

Since we rotated around the z axis by 90 degrees we can say the following about the earlier deduction of the matrix coefficients:

```
R00 = cos(θ)
R01 = sin(θ)
R02 = cos(θ)
```

And finally, applying this to the matrix:

```
cos(θ)     sin(θ)     cos(θ)
  0          0          0
  0          0          0
```

After building my matrix, I've tested it here:
[Matrix Calculation Online Website](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%260%260%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dcos%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%26sin%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%26cos%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5C%5C%20%200%260%260%5C%5C%20%200%260%260%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D)

With the following same vector `A [1 0 0]` and matrix `R` I ended up with
And got the desired Result of `At [0 1 0]`

So, summing it all the process I've done, my question is why for every resource I looked for the answer the rotating around the z axis matrix should look like this: [Z axis rotation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo0De.png)

What have I done wrong / missed calculating to get the same matrix ?

Comment: You should test some different cases (maybe you have).  It is very easy to get the right result accidentally.

Comment: @Carser I suppose you're right, but that would only make me realize that the way I found this matrix is wrong I wish to know how to be able to compute it

Comment: Well it seems you've designed your matrix specifically for the case of $90^\circ$, whereas the rotation matrix you link to is the more general case for any angle $\theta$.  Basically, you're case is the specific instance for the general matrix where $\theta = 90^\circ$.

Comment: @Carser I see, could you tell me on how could I design it for any value of θ

Comment: As a quick sanity check of your solution, remember that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. The matrix you’ve ended up with collapses everything onto the $x$-axis! This can’t possibly be right, since, among other things, the $z$-axis shouldn’t be affected at all by this rotation.

Comment: By the way, kudos for trying to work this out on your own instead of just looking it up somewhere.

Comment: @amd thanks, it's more fun understanding what it means :)
Also I found this document http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/RotationDerivation.pdf which might be help to some people. I think my problem is that I've never been shown on how to prove such thing so I just tried to figure something out. This document shows how to get to the matrix for z-axis rotation. I'm gonna practice the same method to design the other 2 axes rotation matrices :)

Comment: If you understand how to derive a 2-d rotation, you shouldn’t have much trouble working out 3-d rotations about all three axes. Be careful, though. In one of the cases, a coordinate axis gets flipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've designed a set of equations specifically for the case of $\theta=90^\circ$.  If you want to derive the more general rotation matrix about axis $z$, then you have to allow for any rotation $\theta$.

Consider rotating some vector like your vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ or slightly more generally $\begin{bmatrix} r \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ around the $z$ axis by an arbitrary angle $\theta$.
[image] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#/media/File:Counterclockwise_rotation.png)

The position of the head of the new vector can be calculated using trigonometry.  It's really the same mathematics as polar coordinates where here you're rotating a radius of $r$.

So the new $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the vector head position can be found with
$$
x = r \cos(\theta)
$$
$$
y = r \sin(\theta)
$$
Writing this with matrices gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & \sin(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This gives a slightly more general formula but requires the vector start parallel to the $x$ axis.  We can generalize further by considering rotating any vector $\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{bmatrix}$ in 3D about the $z$ axis.  Using the same trig we can deduce that the new $x$ position of the vector head is
$$
x = v_x \cos(\theta) - v_y\sin(\theta) 
$$
the new $y$ position is 
$$
y = v_x \sin(\theta) + v_y\cos(\theta) 
$$
and since we're rotating around $z$ the $v_z$ value does not change 
$$
z = v_z
$$
which writing with matrices gives you the rotation matrix you'll recognize
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) &  -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Could you explain what you said for a 3D vector "x=vxcos(θ)−vysin(θ)" and "y=vxsin(θ)+vycos(θ)" how did you got to this equation, comparing it to the method I used to design the matrix I don't quite understand what you did here